# Using global resource in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use global resource in my javascript code. Normally, when the code is inside the ASP code, I use 
`<%=GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "MONTHS_SHORT1") %>` 
and it works. But, when the javascript code is not inside the ASP code, for example in a folder as calendar.js, it does not work. How can I use the global resource in this case? Note: The resource file is inside my App_GlobalResources folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following post I created describing how you can serialise global and local resources and retrieve them from javascript using jQuery and JSON.

http://bloggingdotnet.blogspot.com/2010_02_01_archive.html

Firstly, create a new handler (.ashx) file. This one was written quite some time ago, so uses vb.net and custom JSON serialisation:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Resources
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Localisation
  Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

  Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim files As String = context.Request.QueryString("files")
    Dim local As String = context.Request.QueryString("local")
    Dim isLocal As Boolean
    Dim folder As String = "App_GlobalResources"

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript"

    'Write out file as object
    context.Response.Write("{")

    'Determine if local resource file
    If local IsNot Nothing Then
      isLocal = CBool(local)
      If isLocal Then folder = "App_LocalResources"
    End If
    If files Is Nothing OrElse files.Length = 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Parameter 'files' was not provided in querystring.")

    Dim flag As Boolean = False
    For Each file As String In files.Split(",")
      If flag Then context.Response.Write(",")

      Dim className As String = file.Split(".")(0)

      'Write the class (name of the without any extensions) as the object
      context.Response.Write(className)
      context.Response.Write(":{")

      'Open the resx xml file
      Dim filePath As String = context.Server.MapPath("~\" & folder & "\" & file)
      Dim document As New XmlDocument()
      Dim flag2 As Boolean = False
      document.Load(filePath)

      Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes("//data")

      For Each node As XmlNode In nodes

        'Write out the comma seperator
        If flag2 Then context.Response.Write(",")

        Dim attr As XmlAttribute = node.Attributes("name")
        Dim resourceKey As String = attr.Value
        context.Response.Write(resourceKey)
        context.Response.Write(":""")

        'Write either the local or global value
        If isLocal Then
        context.Response.Write(HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(String.Format("~/{0}",    file.Replace(".resx", "")), resourceKey)) 'Has to be full path to the .aspx page
        Else
          context.Response.Write(HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(className, resourceKey))
        End If
        context.Response.Write("""")

        'Flag that we need a comma seperator
        flag2 = True
      Next

      context.Response.Write("}")
      flag = True
    Next

    'End file
    context.Response.Write("}")
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
      Return True
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

When that is working, use the following jQuery code to make an ajax call to the http handler and return the contents of the resource file as an object literal.

```
// -- Localisation --
var localResources;
var globalResources;

//Sample JSON for javascript resource values eg {TrackDetail:{HideHelp:"Hide Help", ShowHelp:"Show Help"}}
//Usage e.g: alert(localResources.TrackDetail.HideHelp);

//Load Localisation values into variables so that they can be available on the client
//Note that these values are loaded asynchronously, the code in the function will not run until the call has completed.
$.getJSON('Localisation.ashx?files=TrackDetail.aspx.resx&local=true', function(data) { localResources = data});
$.getJSON('Localisation.ashx?files=Errors.resx,Strings.resx', function(data) { globalResources = data});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to generate JavaScript code that mimics the resources you need, as ASP.NET runs server-side, and JavaScript runs client-side.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var MONTHS_SHORT1 = <%=GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "MONTHS_SHORT1") %>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use a hidden literal to hold the resource text then grab the localised text using javascript and jquery:

```
  <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" visible="false" Text="<%$ Resources:String, MyResourceText%>" />
  <input type="button" id="Button1"  value=""  />
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Update the buton text with the correct localised lookup
                var ButtonText = '<%=Literal1.Text%>';
                $("#Button1").attr('value', ButtonText );
            });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will register resource key.

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

String scriptRegVariables = string.Format("var resourcetext = '{0}'", Resources.Resource.keyText);
if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("RegVariablesScript"))
{
    cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(_Default), "RegVariablesScript", scriptRegVariables, true);
}
```

Now inside .js file you can directly use it.
e.g. Alert(resourcetext);

Add the code above on Page_Load of control or aspx page